# sending email to self using python smtplib

Tags: python, smtplib

Hi need some help in regards to python smtplib. Code works as per below

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

sender = "sender@abc.com"
subject = "Test Email"
to_list = ["recipient@xyz.com"]
cc_list = ["sender@abc.com"]
bcc_list = ["sender@abc.com"]

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
body = "<B> This is </B> a test message"
emailbody = MIMEText(body, 'html')
msg.attach(emailbody)

msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = ",".join(to_list)
msg['Cc'] = ",".join(cc_list)


recipients = to_list + cc_list + bcc_list

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
```

The code works and able to receive by the recipient. However, the email is not received by cc and/or bcc, in which it sending to itself. Using Python 2.6.6 / (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2

[EDIT]

I have somewhat isolated the issue. If I use xx@abc.com as sender, xx@abc.com and xx@xyz.com will be able to receive the email. However, when I use **xx@xyz.com** as sender, only **xx@abc.com** will be able to receive the email. Could this be an issue on the SMTP server or is there any parameter that I can use in smtplib? Below is the output **Note**: I have replaced some info with xxxxxxxxxx :) :

```
>>> s.sendmail(sender, toaddrs, msg.as_string())
send: 'ehlo [xxxxxxxxxx]\r\n'
reply: '250-xxxxxxxxxx\r\n'
reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 10240000\r\n'
reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: xxxxxxxxxx
PIPELINING
SIZE 10240000
VRFY
ETRN
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
8BITMIME
DSN
send: 'mail FROM:<xxxxxxxxxx> size=425\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Ok
send: 'rcpt TO:<XXXXXXXXXXXX>\r\n'
reply: '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
data: (354, 'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\r\n\tboundary="===============2153749063822088494=="\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nSubject: Test Email\r\nFrom: xxxxxxxxxx\r\nTo: xxxxxxxxxx\r\nCc: xxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxx.com\r\n\r\n--===============2153749063822088494==\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n<B> This is </B> a test message\r\n--===============2153749063822088494==--\r\n.\r\n'
reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 173532000045\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 173532000045
data: (250, '2.0.0 Ok: queued as 173532000045')
{}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does that `s.sendmail()` return? The return value should tell you if some recipients were rejected, and possibly why. If neither From nor Cc is local to your server, then it's possible the mail server just denied the relaying. May be a good idea to ensure at least the envelope sender is something the mail server thinks is local.

Comment: I have edited the question with the output of s.sendmail() :)

Comment: Hmm, it is weird that there are no `RCPT TO:` commands in the transcript of the trace of the sendmail command. I would expect some `send: 'rcpt TO: ...'`... In addition `reply: '354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'` looks like the reply for a `DATA` command that is not displayed either. Are you sure you didn't forget some lines?

Comment: Did you check your `spam` folder?

Comment: @ Kishor Yes. I already checked the spam folder and and the email is not there. If I used a different sender domain, the email will be received straight in the inbox.

@Serge I may have missed out the RCPT TO: but there is

send: 'mail FROM:<xxxxxxx> size=425\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Ok
send: 'rcpt TO:<xxxxxxx>\r\n'
reply: '250 2.1.5 Ok\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.5 Ok

Comment: Your code works fine, I tried on my machine. I used my work email and personal email to test the case you isolated. It sends the email in both cases.

Comment: Flagging to close as unreproducible. If one of the domains is gmail, maybe you want to mention that.

Comment: If you have access to the Postfix queue on the server, maybe examine what happened to queue entry 173532000045 but this is no longer a programming question anyway.

Comment: What matters to know whether the Python code or the SMTP server configuration is the cause is the list of the RCPT TO commands. If you have 3 addresses in the `recipients` list and can find them all in the `RCPT TO` commands, then the problem is in server.

Comment: It is something work related so my worry is that I may disclose some info that may flagged by the company, its not gmail btw. I see. as mentioned by @Kishor, the code works and might not be related to programming question anyway. On the side note, don't have access on the server. 

Thanks for the comments. :)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, I can find RCPT TO in all of the recipients addresses. Thanks. :)